# Using Laravel eloquent to search if a value in a database column appears in search string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I currently working on a laravel 5.4 project where I'm trying to find values in my database that are similar to a search string introduced. For example, I have the following search term

`$search_term = "Some long phrase with words"`

and in my database (MySQL) I have a table `tags` with a column `value`. One row in this table would have `value => 'some'`, another row might have `value => 'long'`, and another row might have `value => 'phra'`

What I need is to create a collection of all tags where the `value` appears in my search term. Which means the 3 rows i mentioned should match for my `$search_term`

I currently know that I can use eloquent in laravel and say something like

`Tag::where('value', 'like', "%".$search_term."%")->get()`

But as far as I understand this would see if the `$search_term` is a sub-string of what's in the `value` column.

How can I use eloquent to ask if `value` is contained (a sub-string) in `$search_term`?

Comment: Split your search term into an array of single words using PHP. Then use `->whereIn('tag', $words)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REGEXP, which is a regular expression search. However, since you're comparing the field to your variable, you're going to have to switch things around a bit and use a raw query:

```
 TAG::whereRaw('? REGEXP value', [$search_term])->get();
```

Comment: Do you mean REGEXP is a keyword or that I need to enter my regular expression here?

Comment: `REGEXP` is a keyword/operator, just like `LIKE` is.

Comment: `'scary search term' REGEXP 'car'` will return TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer this, because not every string is valid regexp.

```
TAG::whereRaw('? LIKE CONCAT("%", value, "%")',
    [$search_term])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for an eloquent solution, but maybe just solve it with php? You could do something like:

```
$tags = Tag::all();
$tags_found = collect([]);

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    if(strpos($search_term, $tag->value) !== false)
        $tags_found->push($tag)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your search term into an array of single words using PHP.

```
$search_term = "Some long phrase, with words!";

$words = preg_replace('/\W+/', ' ', $search_term);
$words = trim($words);
$words = explode(' ', $words);
```

Now `$words` contains

```
array (
  0 => 'Some',
  1 => 'long',
  2 => 'phrase',
  3 => 'with',
  4 => 'words',
)
```

And you can search with

```
Tag::whereIn('value', $words)->get();
```

Note: `preg_replace('/\W+/', ' ', $search_term);` will replace any sequence of non-word characters with a single white space.

Comment: my problem with this is that I can't guarantee that the value in the database is one word. It is possible for the sake of context that this value be a phrase and not just a word...